# UWSGI startup subprocess error

Tags: subprocess, uwsgi, popen, python-3.6

I am trying to start application with command

```
uwsgi_python36 --chdir=/var/www/uap/uap/ --virtualenv=/var/www/virtenv/uap/ --uid=deploy --module=project.wsgi --master --http-socket=127.0.0.1:8028 --max-requests=2000 --vacuum
```

Such config for UWSGI works fine for uwsgi and python 3.4 and python 2.7 in other projects. But we started update to python 3.6 and have an error. Traceback of the startup error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/var/www/virtenv/uap/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
...
  File "/var/www/virtenv/uap/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_filters/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .filterset import FilterSet
  File "/var/www/virtenv/uap/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .conf import settings
...
  File "/var/www/virtenv/uap/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coreapi/auth.py", line 2, in <module>
    from requests.auth import AuthBase, HTTPBasicAuth
  File "/var/www/virtenv/uap/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/var/www/virtenv/uap/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 42, in <module>
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/platform.py", line 755, in _syscmd_uname
    f = os.popen('uname %s 2> %s' % (option, DEV_NULL))
  File "/var/www/virtenv/uap/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 978, in popen
    bufsize=buffering)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1260, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: fork_exec() argument 4 must be tuple, not list
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

I have tried to execute `platform.system()` and it's worked fine.

Does anybody have ideas about this error and how to fix it?